# Dspace showing Blank Page

Tags: tomcat, dspace

I've been using Dspace 5 for some time but now it is not working properly. I succesfully uploaded some data to dspace but now whenever i log in and start to navigate, some minutes later it goes blank and it doesn't show anything. The only solution is to restart tomcat server.

I checked error logs (dspace, tomcat, cocoon) but i couldn't find any clue about the error. Dspace is running over a VPS which has 1 GB ram and 80 GB SSD. I would like to know what can i do to find more info that let me solve this issue.

[image: Dspace blank Repo]

Comment: It is possible that one of the background tasks (index-discovery or filter-media) is consuming a large amount of resources.  The next time that you stop tomcat, check for any processes running as dspace (except the handle service).  Perhaps there is a stray process that needs to be killed.

Comment: It might be helpful to post the tomcat log in particular somewhere public -- the most common cause of this issue in my experience is tomcat running out of memory. It would be good to be sure that isn't the problem in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the information you have given, namely the fact that it just occurs after a few minutes of random browsing. I would guess that this is due to tomcat running out of (permGen) memory-space after a certain amount of iterations. You can check for this in your logs.

I would suggest launching tomcat, and giving it more memory, using launch options like
`-Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

You can see how much memory you actually need / can give it.

When you hit a memory issue like this, it should also be visible in the logs though. You said you could not find it, but I am quite sure that it is in the tomcat log somewhere. It is a bit odd that you could not find this, but not impossible to overlook I assume.